# What do symbols mean in IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb

I couldn't find anything about this in ruby-doc.

I can have such things in IRB :

```
2.2.0 :012">
```

or

```
2.2.0 :012?>
```

I don't know what those symbols mean. Do you know `?` Is it to warn that I missed one *?* or one *"*   ?

Comment: expand the issue. Do you mean, that you opened `"` and never closed it, and IRB tells you about it by marking each new line with `?` sing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [rvm](https://rvm.io/), they have a custom irb.rc [file](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/irbrc.rb) that define a few different behaviors for `irb`. In particular, there's this section:

```
@prompt = {
  :PROMPT_I => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n > ",  # default prompt
  :PROMPT_S => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n%l> ", # known continuation
  :PROMPT_C => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n > ",
  :PROMPT_N => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n?> ", # unknown continuation
  :RETURN => " => %s \n",
  :AUTO_INDENT => true
}
```

So the `?` means that it's an unknown continuation, and it isn't sure how to prompt you to complete your current command. The `"` shows when you have an unmatched quote, like this:

```
irb(main):024:0> "foo
irb(main):025:0" "
=> "foo\n"
irb(main):026:0>
```